# After Insert Trigger never fires using Import Wizard

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Using Import Wizard I tried importing data into tables `tcc_Block` and `PROJECT_IDENTITY`.

These 2 table structures already exist in SQL Server and they are related via the `ProjectID` columns. `PROJECT_IDENTITY` has `ProjectID` as PK and `tcc_Block` as FK key.

Any time I import tables, the `ProjectID` in the parent table is created and incremented, but the one in the child table is always `NULL`.

The trigger never fires!?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTest]
ON [dbo].[tcc_Block]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @proj int;

    SELECT @proj = MAX(ProjectID) 
    FROM PROJECT_IDENTITY;

    UPDATE tcc_Block
    SET ProjectID = @proj
    WHERE ProjectID IS NULL;
END;
GO
```

Comment: **DO NOT** use `MAX(ProjectID)` to get the newly inserted ID - that's crappy and unreliable - use the `Inserted` pseudo table inside the trigger! That's the reliable way to do it. But also keep in mind: there could be **multiple rows** in `Inserted` if your `INSERT` statement inserted multiple rows - you have to take a **proper, set-based** approach to reading out those values - don't just do a `SELECT @ID = ID FROM Inserted` - that's guaranteed to yield incorrect results!

Comment: I have tried using SELECT @ID = ID FROM Inserted but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

[Bulk inserts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) generally do not fire triggers, unless it is explicitly set (see `FIRE_TRIGGERS`) option. If this package is edited in SSIS (Import Export Wizard generates SSIS packages), you can select the Fire triggers option on the Bulk Insert Task Editor Options page. But Import Export Wizard does not expose a way to set this option. You can save the package to file system and edit it in Visual Studio to enable this option, or you can export the data as flat files and import them with `BULK INSERT` command, specifying FIRE_TRIGGERS option.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a SQL 2008 Export that I saved as a dtsx package in File System. So, I opened the package in my SSMS 2016 and it opens as an xml file. I found the "FastLoadOptions" property: property id="72" name="FastLoadOptions".
Then scrolled to the end of the line where the options are entered and added "FIRE_TRIGGERS":

> TABLOCK,CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,FIRE_TRIGGERS /property>. 
>   Saved it and reloaded into my job step (don't forget to check the "Use 32 Bit runtime" on the Execution option tab). And it works great.